# Fontconfig warning on OSX when running Octave

Tags: fontconfig

I am getting the following warning/error when running some octave files. I have installed octave using `homebrew` following the guide [here](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X#Homebrew). Seems like I have to remove the line from the config, but couldn't find where it is stored.

```
Fontconfig warning: line 146: blank doesn't take any effect anymore. please remove it from your fonts.conf
```

Answer (score 4):

The warning happens because when you upgraded fontconfig, it did not overwrite the old fonts.conf file.

In my case, the full path was `/usr/local/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`

To solve the issue remove (or rename) the old fonts.conf file and reinstall fontconfig.

```
mv /usr/local/etc/fonts/fonts.conf /usr/local/etc/fonts/fonts.conf.bak
brew reinstall fontconfig
```

The file will be regenerated automatically for the new version.

Answer (score 3):

If fontconfig has been installed via homebrew, the file is located here: `/usr/local/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`

See `brew info fontconfig` to test if the package has been installed.

Comment: In the warning I see, the path is provided which is the same as in this answer. Removing the `blank` start and end tags solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Should be here:

```
~/Library/Fonts/fonts.conf
```